# if command to test for integer(0)

Tags: r

I'm using a command to return the points at which participants reach 8 contiguous responses in a row. The command is:

```
 test <- which( rle(goo)$values==1 & rle(goo)$lengths >= 8)
```

where:

```
 goo <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

if the participant never achieves 8 contiguous responses i'd like to set the variable "test" to equal -1. As it stands, the command returns integer(0) when 8 contiguous responses in a row are not found. I've tried writing an if command but can't seem to get it right.

Thanks in advance,

Will

Comment: Why not use logical TRUE and FALSE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining @kohske and @hadley answers into one-liner you get

```
if(!any(test <- which(rle(goo)$values == 1 & 
                      rle(goo)$lengths >= 8))) test<- -1
```

Answer (score 15):

If test is integer(0) then its length is 0. You can also coerce it to logical with `!`

```
length(test)
0
!(length(test)
TRUE    # and would be FALSE for any vector with normal length
> !(length( c(1,2,3) ))
[1] FALSE
```

So:

```
> if ( !length(test) ) {test<- -1} 

> test
[1] -1
```

Comment: Nice, but why not simply `if (!length(test)) test <- -1` ?

Comment: Or use `any(rle(goo)$values==1 & rle(goo)$lengths >= 8)`.

Comment: Or by following DRY principle: `with(rle(goo), any(values == 1 & lengths >= 8))`